# Image Bird's view and image stitching for surround view in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, perspective, image-stitching

Hi everyone I am working on Surround view system for car. I have four 180 degree FOV camera. I have made the setup as shown in this image.[Surround view set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q9C2.jpg)

I am trying to develop this system using opencv c++. 
steps are following

STEP I - Distortion correction

STEP II - Bird's eye view

STEP III - Image stitching

After collecting videos from  four different camera I have corrected distortion and getting following images.

1- [Front camera image after distortion correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Sgb.jpg),

2- [Right camera image after distortion correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhirz.jpg),

After Distortion correction I did Bird's eye view from [anujonthemove birds-eye-view.cpp](https://gist.github.com/anujonthemove/7b35b7c1e05f01dd11d74d94784c1e58) and getting following images as result.

[Front - Bird's eye view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LHwx.jpg)

[Right - Bird's eye view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5swz.jpg)

After this I am trying to stitch all four images using `stitching class reference` from `opencv` and getting error `<NEED MORE IMAGES>`
I have some question.

Q1 - Is my approach correct?

Q2 - Weather Bird's eye view output correct?

Q3 - How to stitch images for surround view like I want to stitch Front and Right image in L shape?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the error. For the SVS you need 4 images right? where are you considering the other 2 images?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have to address the same problem, if possible, would you please to share your improved code? thank you very much.